# Hooking a keypress while still maintaining the original command in C#

Tags: c#, key, hook, keypress

I want to detect a keypress and execute certain events accordingly while my application runs in the background. For example when i press W, I want my application to detect this, write "W pressed" in lets say a listbox and not influence any other process that's going on.

The following code I found does pretty much what I said above. The only problem is that it intercepts the keypress completely. If, for example, I open up google and type "W", the letter does not appear in the google search bar but will be hooked by the application.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {


     // DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

     const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;


     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         // Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
         // Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
         // ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
         RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.W);
     }


     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
     {
         if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
         {
             // My hotkey has been typed

             // Do what you want here
             // ...
             lstLog.Items.Add("W pressed");
         }
         base.WndProc(ref m);
     }
  }
}
```

So, in short. I am looking for a way to hook a keypress while still maintaining the original command. In my example above the "W" should appear in the google search bar.

I have been searching for a solution for this (probably little) problem and found a lot of 
posts about public keys and hooks like the one above, but none really worked the way I would like it to. So I decided to make my first post here. Hope you guys can help me. If there is anything unclear just let me know.

Thx

-EDIT-

Some additional information:
I do plan on using this program while playing games like League of Legends, WoW, etc. So I would like it to not interact with any process of these games due to a possible ban for use of 3rd party software. If there is anything that I should know regarding this then please tell me. Me and my future not banned account thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) interface

Comment: This is just inappropriate use of RegisterHotKey(), it is only useful to implement hot keys.  Intercepting typing keys like W requires writing a WH_KEYBOARD hook.  You cannot write such hooks in C#, it requires a DLL that can be injected into every process.

Comment: I should add that I plan on using this application with some games like League of Legends, WoW, etc. I don't exactly know what you mean with inserting a DLL and have only just googled it for the first time. But I want to avoid stuff that is too complicated and would possibly interact with the game, since that might lead to some kind of ban due to use of 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `RegisterHotKey` as it won't pass the key-event through.

You have to use a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` Hook.

This is a fully functional sample, quick and dirty, but functional:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace StackoverflowHooks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public uint vkCode;
            public uint scanCode;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }


        IntPtr hHook;
        private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
        HookProc lpfn;

        private IntPtr KeyboardHookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT data = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            MessageBox.Show("Pressed key: " + (Keys)data.vkCode);

            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
            SetHook();
        }

        private void SetHook()
        {
            int id_hook = 13; //WH_KEYBOARD_LL - HOOK
            lpfn = new HookProc(this.KeyboardHookProc);
            using (ProcessModule curModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule)
            hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(id_hook, lpfn, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }
}
```